# Digital signage [ Pi and Android application ]

Tags: pi-3, android

Recently i was working on **Digital Signage** and i want to make a portable device [Pi] and i want to manage it from **mobile application**. is there any plugin or code that i can embed in android java application and manage the signage over pi.**[with/ without internet]**
I have tried many like Yodeck, piSignage, noob etc but they have there own web interface. so what i want is to need a chunk of code or plugin or sdk to embed in application and communicate with pi.

Thanks

Comment: There's a lot of irrelevant information and not much relevant information in the question. Are you trying to send data between a Pi and an Android device, over an IP network? How about http? Well supported everywhere. If that's not suitable, why not? (i.e. what unwritten requirements do you have? We don't know your project.)

Comment: I'm just working on my FYP and it's the sub-module that i have to display the product over TV (whether smart or not). For that i need a bridge btw android studio app and pi.

Comment: And is HTTP suitable? If not, why not?  Then perhaps someone can suggest something more suitable. It's still very unclear what your requirements are.